# Pagination - hide for users visible for search engines

Tags: jquery, css, pagination

I load blog posts by infinite loading jquery script. But I wanted to make it crawlers friendly and include as well normal pagination links, but those has to be hidden for the users (with enabled javascript), how would I do that?

With display:hidden? Is  that a correct way to do it? Or I will just hide it by javascript on page load? Thanks a lot.

Comment: It wouldn't be good practice to hide for a user the way you describe. What about having a widget on the page that lists links to all blog posts, then the  search engine will detect the links into the other posts not shown on the homepage ?

Comment: @grimmus Unfortunately, it's not possible (because of clients requirements). Only infinite loading and no other links visible. It's not a blog page, it's a company website with few articles per month.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide right in CSS via `display:none` or any way you want. Just don't generate different html for humans and for bots.